# Could a ViewModel be updated when the Activity is in background?

Tags: android, rx-android, android-viewmodel

When I have an Activity (A) with a ViewModel-A subscribed to Rx data, and I open a new Activity (B).

Does the ViewModel (A) still listen changes??

Imagine the situation when I have ViewModel-A subscribed to a Rx that return Data each time I change something.  If I access to the Activity-B and I do any change to this Data, 
**Will the ViewModel-A be notified?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your viewmodel live as long as your activity so you can do whatever you want while your activity is alive (even if it isn't visible)